# Can CSS target a forward slash in an element?

Tags: jquery, css

I have `<span class="bold">Class 1 / Class 2 / Class 3</span>`. I wonder if CSS can target forward slash so that only Class 3 is bold.

Comment: Not with CSS alone. With jQuery sure, but have you tried anything?

Comment: Just put a `<span>` inside the other `<span>`? `<span>Class 1 / Class 2 / <span class="bold">Class 3</span></span>`

Comment: @BrianGlaz He probably knows it but I doubt thats the case.

Comment: Thanks, Brian! It is dynamic so that cannot put `<span>` inside

Comment: I am trying to use `lastIndexOf("/")` in JQuery, but it doesn't work, yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think this is possible with CSS but you can accomplish this with some jQuery and CSS combined.

```js
jQuery.fn.unbold = function (str, className) {    
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");

    return this.each(function () {
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(matched) {return "<span class='unbold'>" + matched + "</span>";});
    });
};

$(".bold").unbold("^(.*[\\\/])","unbold");
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.unbold {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='bold'>Class 1 / Class 2 / Class 3</span>
```

This bolds the entire html then finds the string before the last forward slash and unbolds everything before the last forward slash.

Comment: Thank you very much Anthony! It works for 3 classes, but some case it has only 2 classes, or 4 classes.  Sorry, this is my bad that I didn't mention before.  I try to write something like `$(function(){
 $("#classes").lastIndexOf("/").addClass("bold");
};` , it doesn't work

Comment: It should work for 2 classes or 4 classes. The function keeps the last class bold. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/n642o1wd/1/

Comment: Here's a way to target just the third class.. not the last: https://jsfiddle.net/n642o1wd/5/

Answer (score 0):

No, but a [:last-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) can something like this, but you need more tags https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrqOdx 
html

```
<span class="spanEl">
  <p>this</p>
  <p>there</p>
  <p>that</p>
</span>
```

css

```
   .spanEl p:last-child {
      font-weight:bold;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If Class 3 is always in the third position you could do:

HTML:

```
<span class="bold">
  <span>Class 1</span> / 
  <span>Class 2</span> / 
  <span>Class 3</span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.bold,
.bold > span {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.bold > span:nth-of-type(3) {
  font-weight: 800;
}
```